# Lost 3 GB memory from iPhone 4s after update to iTunes 11.4.018

Tags: itunes, iphone, storage

My storage on the iPhone, which I had cleared to 6 GB of free space (I have NOT downloaded 8.0.2) suddenly, after iTunes software update, went down to 3 GB of free space!
This happened *just* with iTunes software update on my computer, followed by a sync.

<sup>iPhone 4s with 16 GB capacity. iOS 7.0. I downloaded latest iTunes version to my computer 11.4.018.</sup>

Comment: The iTunes it self is 340 MB, so how big is your library ?

Comment: @Buscar Could you clarify the link between the size of iTunes and the aforementioned situation?

Comment: i have the same problem. I lost over 3gb of space sicne the update and cant find anything to remove

Comment: Not clear to me which file is using the 3 Gig? the iTunes it self ? check the Settings > General > Usage ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my phone - the space was being taken up by the download and unpacked iOS 8, which was waiting to be installed. Once I installed the software - the "missing" space appeared again, and the bar displaying my drive capacity was reflecting correctly.

I would check that first - to see if it already downloaded the update.  The link will say "Install Now" on the Settings > General > Software Update page in iOS.

Regards,

Ed

Answer (score 0):

Ed, Thanks! Looks like iOS 8.0.2 *was* downloaded with iTunes even though I didn't request it.

Where it used to ask if I wanted to download iOS 8.0.2, it NOW says "Install Now" as you pointed out.  (Also, it no longer says I need 5.8 GB of space, even though I only have 3 GB left.That must be because it ALREADY used 3 GB downloading iOS 8.0.2.)

I appreciate the thoughtful replies.